# cordova build error on ubuntu when trying to build from terminal

Tags: android, ios, xml, cordova, ant

I am getting the following error when trying to build sencha app in terminal on ubuntu meachine..

```
edge@edge-HP:~/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova$ cordova build
Running command: /home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/build 
Buildfile: /home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/build.xml
```

BUILD FAILED

```
/home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find



/home/transnoesis/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from 

/home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/build.xml
```

Total time: 0 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-

```
f,/home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /home/edge/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: Please mention the steps you have taken?

Comment: sencha app build(Build Success) but cordova build (Build Failed) i.e edge@edge-HP:~/Desktop/Anupam2014/MobileAtSite_Aug23/cordova$ cordova build

Comment: plz modify the question and mention it there..thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks **path settings issue** and is unable to find path to sdk & ant tools.

Currently I am on Windows and see how I've set paths on Windows, so you check and set yours accordingly on Ubuntu, hope will help you.

**ANT_Home:** `C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4`

**Java_Home:** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`

**ANDROID_HOME:** `C:\Android\AndroidSDK\sdk`

**path**`:.;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;`